# Tascam DR100 iPod USB Charging

Tags: tascam

I have got a Tascam DR100. I don't want to shell out more for the charger. Now, it says you can charge via USB and a laptop, which is fair enough. CAN I use my Apple USB charging plug, connect the USB and just charge it that way, with the right size cable?

Will it charge like it is just plugged into a laptop, or will it melt and fuck my device!!?

A quick google search hasn't really cleared it up. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The voltage on the Apple charger is USB spec:  5V.
Where the apple chargers differ from USB spec is in the current available.  Most current generation Apple USB chargers can provide 1A (1000mA) of current, double the 500mA that is the USB standard.  This is why high current Apple devices like the iPad won't charge over USB when connected to the computer.  It needs a full 1A of current.

However, for your application it should be fine, since your Apple charger will provide plenty of current necessary to charge the DR100.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. I have also used some cheap universal charger with no problems.